# Application of continuous dependence to show that the component solutions are positive.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

recently we've been covering the concept of continuous dependence of ODE solutions to its initial condition. In showing the applications of this, my professor showed us some examples where you can use continuous dependence and quasi positivity to show that the component solutions are positive.

So the posed question is:

**For an ODE $x'=f(t,x), \ f: \mathbb R \times \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$, with $x_j(t_0) \geq 0,\ j=1,...,n$, under what conditions is $x_j(t) \geq 0 $ for $j=1,...,n$ and $t \geq t_0$?**

Then he goes on to define quasi-positivity as:

**$f$ is quasi-positive if $x_j \geq 0, \ \forall j=1,...,n$ and $f_j(t,x) \geq 0$ for all $j$ such that $x_j=0$**

Now the part I don't understand is the following example, where he shows why some $f$ is quasi positive:

**Example (Chemical equilibrium model)**
Let $n = 3$ and $f$ is defined by $$x_1' = - Ax_1x_2 + Bx_3 = f_1,$$ $$x_2'=-Ax_1x_2+Bx_3 = f_2,$$ $$x_3'=Ax_1x_2-Bx_3=f_3$$ for constants $A,B > 0$. Then $$x_1=0 \implies f_1(0,x_2,x_3)=Bx_3, \ Bx_3 \geq 0 \text{ if } x_3 \geq 0,$$ $$x_2=0 \implies f_2(x_1,0,x_3)=Bx_3, \ Bx_3 \geq 0 \text{ if } x_3 \geq 0,$$ $$x_3=0 \implies f_3(x_1,x_2,0)=Ax_1x_2, \ Ax_1x_2 \geq 0 \text{ if } x_1,\ x_2 \geq 0$$
so that $f$ is quasi positive.

Here I am confused as to what $x_j$ are and why one can simply subsitute a fixed value into $f_j$ to deduce that $f$ is quasi positive.

**My guess** is that the $x_j$'s are the initial conditions, i.e. $x_j = x_j(t_0)$, but unfortunately that's all I can think about right now.

Does anybody know an alternative/ detailed definition of quasi positivity and/ or understand why this example is quasi positive and could explain it?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove that the state remains nonnegative, then you must show that when the state reaches the boundary of the nonnegative orthant, then it should not cross it.

Since each state has its own dynamics, then it is sufficient to show that when a state is zero at some time, then its derivative is always nonnegative, otherwise it may go negative.

Since the dynamics of the state $x_i$ is given by $f_i(x)$, then the condition is that $f_i(x)\ge0$ for all $x\ge0$ such that $x_i=0$, and this must hold for all $i$. In this case, $x$ is a just a value of the state that lies on the boundary of the nonnegative orthant. It can be an initial point or any other point on the trajectory of the system.

All those conditions combined ensure that when the state reaches the boundary of the nonnegative orthant, it is repelled from it. In other words, the nonnegative orthant is invariant for the dynamics of the system.

This idea generalizes to any cone $C$ other than the nonnegative orthant. In the case of linear systems, polyhedral cones are usually considered.

Comment: Wow that makes a lot more sense, thanks! Just to clarify, would an analogy of having $x = 0$ as a wall make sense? so everytime $x_j$ is at the wall, the derivative is nonnegative, i.e. we are ensured that the $x_i$ will bounce back into a nonnegative state?

Comment: Yes, except that the wall is of higher dimension.

Comment: @gibster : Note that the wall is uni-directional, it only prevents a crossing in forward time. Crossing from negative coordinates to positive ones is still possible. This is explicitly not possible if $f_i(x)=x_ig_i(x)$ (with continuous or smooth $g$).